# MATLAB: struct.name type and strcmp

Tags: matlab, types, struct, strcmp

I have the following code:

> fonts = dir('fonts')
>
> strcmp('BELL.TTF',fonts.name)

where dir('fonts') returns a 33x1 struct where each entry has name (string), date, and a few other things. I can't figure out what type fonts.name is (if it's a cell array or what), and my end goal is to be able to use strcmp to compare across all of the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fonts.name` is 33 separate character arrays. You want to combine these into a cell array so that you can use it with `strcmp`.

In code:

```
fonts = dir('fonts');
%# use curly brackets to combine the 33 strings into a cell array
tf = strcmp('BELL.TTF',{fonts.name})
```

`tf` is a logical array with 1 wherever `fonts.name` is equal to `'BELL.TTF'`